# C# extension method doesn't seem to exist

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I can't seem to get the following extension method to be found in another class in the same namespace (`MyProject.Util`).

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace MyProject.Util
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string Get(
             this NameValueCollection me,
             string key,
             string def
        )
        {
            return me[key] ?? def;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it's basically another version of `foo[bar] ?? baz`, but I still don't understand why VS2008 fails to compile telling me that no version of `Get` takes two arguments.

Any ideas?

Comment: Close and reopen the solution. Then try compiling.

Comment: @Ismail s: That did not help, I'm afraid.

Comment: Might help to add your calling code.

Comment: *facepalm* The extension class was in fact in a completely new namespace due to a small typo. That was the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you importing your namespace (with `using MyProject.Util`) in the file where you're using the method?  The error message might not be obvious because your extension method has the same name as an existing method.

Comment: He wrote, `in the same namespace`.

Comment: Same name is  not a problem. It is working properly at my end.

Comment: It was a typo in my code making the extensions go in a completely new namespace. Silly me.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the extension method like a static method as in `NameValueCollection.Get`. Try:

```
var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
nameValueCollection.Get( ...
```

Comment: I'm not using it as a static method, that was only me trying to explain the error.

Answer (score 2):

Is the class in the same assembly as the class where it is being used?  If no, have you added a reference to that assembly?

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work for me ...

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace MyProject.Util
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
            nvc.Get(  )
        }
    }
}


namespace MyProject.Util
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string Get(
             this NameValueCollection me,
             string key,
             string def
        )
        {
            return me[key] ?? def;
        }
    }
}
```

Have you checked your target framework?

Comment: Target framework version sounds like the most likely culprit to me. @blahblah: Make sure you're targetting .NET 3.5 or later.

Comment: I've always been using .NET 3.5. I'm doing this in ASP.NET MVC by the way, I'm not even sure I can do that with anything below 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine when I try it.  There's really only one failure mode: forgetting to add a using statement for the namespace that contains the extension method:

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using MyProject.Util;     // <== Don't forget this!
...
    var coll = new NameValueCollection();
    coll.Add("blah", "something");
    string value = coll.Get("blah", "default");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and traced it down to not referencing System.Core (the project was compiled against 3.5, but that reference had accidentally been removed while experimenting with VS2010/.Net 4.0).

Comment: I find `System.Core` when expanding References in my VS2008 project.